# Cannot ssh into Raspberry Pi (root is locked, press enter to continue)

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh

When I first installed raspbian and configured ssh it auto logged in every time and I could just ssh into it.

Now out of nowhere   (seems like it may have been an update?) I cannot just ssh, I have to press enter on keyboard first then I can login through ssh. This is really annoying and defeats the purpose. I have seen a lot of problems like this but none of the solutions have worked so far.

Comment: stuck at same problem. did u find a solution?